# Composition Series of $sl_3(\Bbb C)$

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $Z(\mathbb \lambda)$ denote the standard cyclic(or highest weight) $L$-module of highest weight $\lambda$ and $V(\lambda)$ denote the finite dimensional $L$-module of highest weight $\lambda$. Now for any $\lambda$ $\in$ $H^*$, we know that
$ch_{V(\lambda)}$ = $\sum_{w.\lambda \leq \lambda}$ $b(\lambda,w)ch_{Z(w.\lambda)}$ with $b(\lambda,w)$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$
and $b(\lambda,1)$ = $1$.
For $L$ = $sl_2(\mathbb{C})$, we get $b(\lambda,w)$ = $\pm 1$ where $\lambda$ is a dominant integral weight. I want to find the coefficients $b(\lambda,w)$ for 
$L$ = $sl_3(C)$ where $\lambda$ is a dominant integral weight. I was trying to find it using the fact that the unique proper submodule of $Z(\lambda)$ for $\lambda$ integral dominant is given by $\bigoplus_{\alpha \in \Delta}$ $Z(s_{\alpha}. \lambda)$. Can anyone please help me with this. Thanks for any help.
$Notations$ - $L$ is finite dimensional semisimple Lie algebra,
$\Delta$ is the set of simple roots and $s_{\alpha}$ denotes the simple reflections for $\alpha$ $\in$ $\Delta$,$w. \lambda$ = $w(\lambda$ + $\delta)$ - $\delta$ $\forall$ $w$ $\in$ $W$ where $W$ is the Weyl group and $\delta$ is the half sum of the positive roots.
In general, is it possible to find out how $b(\lambda,w)$ depends on $\lambda$ and $w$ for a dominant integral weight $\lambda$?

Comment: Yes, this has a nice general answer, though probably the specific case here is easier. For the general case one needs Kazhdan-Lusztig theory.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to deal with the specific case of sl_3(C)
without using the theory?I have read Intoduction to Lie Algebras from Humphreys.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have time to work through the details myself right now, but you can get some idea of the things needed by looking at 4.11 and 5.4 in Humphreys' book on Category $\mathcal{O}$ where he treats specifically this case (though you will need to work a bit to get precisely what you are looking for from what he does).